# Повторный вызов текущего блока при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется контейнер в котором находятся блоки с текстом. Каждый блок в свою очередь разделен на части. Все блоки скрыты. При клике на кнопку "читать текст" рандомно выбирается блок и показывается первая его часть с копкой "далее", при нажатии на которую скрывается первая часть текста и показывается вторая. И так до тех пор пока не закончатся все части текста. В последней части имеется кнопка "читать снова", при нажатии на которую скрывается последняя открытая часть текста и начинается новый рандомный выбор и показ блока с текстом.
Тот код что я написал работает правильно если выбор блока с текстом меняется, но в случае если выбор падает на тот же блок что показывается в данный момент, этот блок не начинает показываться заново, т.е. снова его первая часть. Как это исправить?

html:

```
<button class="btnRead">Читать текст</button>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text1 hide">
        <div class="part1">
            Текст 1. Часть 1////////
            <button class="btn btn1">Далее</button>
        </div>
        <div class="part2 hide">
            /////Текст 1. Часть 2////
            <button class="btn btn2">Далее</button>
        </div>
        <div class="part3 hide">
            //////Текст 1. Часть 3
            <button class="btnMore">Читать снова</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text2 hide">
        <div class="part1">
            Текст 2. Часть 1////////
            <button class="btn btn1">Далее</button>
        </div>
        <div class="part2 hide">
            /////Текст 2. Часть 2////
            <button class="btn btn2">Далее</button>
        </div>
        <div class="part3 hide">
            //////Текст 2. Часть 3
            <button class="btnMore">Читать снова</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
$('.btnRead').click(function(){
    choicePart();
});
function choicePart(){
    var text = $('.text' + randomNumber(1, 2)); // рандомный выбор текстового блока
    text.fadeIn(300);
    bitBlock(text, '.btn1', '.part2');
    bitBlock(text, '.btn2', '.part3');

    text.find('.btnMore').click(function(){
        choicePart();
    });
}
function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
// переход по клику к следующей части текста
function bitBlock(blockText, button, nextPart){
    blockText.find(button).click(function(){
        var partOut = $(this).parent();
        var partIn = blockText.find(nextPart);
        partOut.fadeOut(700);
        partOut.replaceWith(partIn);
        partIn.fadeIn(700);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас подход изначально неправильный, как-то так набросал на скорую руку:

```js
$('.btnRead').click(function() {
  choicePart();
});

$('.btnMore').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide().closest('.container').hide().children('.part1').show();
  choicePart();
});

$('.next').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
});

function choicePart() {
  var text = $('.text' + randomNumber(1, 2));

  text.fadeIn(300);
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnRead">Читать текст</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text1 container hide">
    <div class="part1">
      Текст 1. Часть 1////////
      <button class="btn next">Далее</button>
    </div>

    <div class="part2 hide">
      /////Текст 1. Часть 2////
      <button class="btn next">Далее</button>
    </div>
    <div class="part3 hide">
      //////Текст 1. Часть 3
      <button class="btnMore">Читать снова</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text2 container hide">
    <div class="part1">
      Текст 2. Часть 1////////
      <button class="btn next">Далее</button>
    </div>
    <div class="part2 hide">
      /////Текст 2. Часть 2////
      <button class="btn next">Далее</button>
    </div>
    <div class="part3 hide">
      //////Текст 2. Часть 3
      <button class="btnMore">Читать снова</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```